# How can I automate upgrading of gems

Tags: mine-defense

I've got myself a pretty solid gem income through transmuting ants, it's all normals gems though, and I need flawless gems for making more rock golems.
I've already build the auto-smithy, but that only upgrades 10 gems per second. Which is horribly slow. Is there any other way to automate the upgrading of gems, or do I have to manually upgrade them by going through the forge menu?

I'm aware that manual upgrading the gems doesn't take much time, but I can't do so when I am not looking at the game.

Comment: Can't build multiple, sorry, I was hopeful that would to speed things up for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The auto-smithy can be upgraded at a cost of stone and gold to speed up the gem combination rate.  Unfortunately, you can't run multiple auto-smithies, so upgrading your existing one is currently the best option I can find.

> There are also bonus upgrades that drastically (10x) improve the autosmithy as you progress through the rest of the game. – GodEmperorDune

I've now personally confirmed this to be true.  (Not that I didn't believe him, just that I don't put it in an answer until I can confirm it ^_^)

Comment: There are also bonus upgrades that drastically (10x) improve the autosmithy as you progress through the rest of the game.